# Run a JS function on Server every 5 minutes

Tags: ajax, serverside-javascript

I apologize if the way I'm asking this is why I haven't found an answer yet, but I've got a simple JS script that makes an AJAX request and gets data from an API and stores it.

I'd like to put that script on a server and have it run every 5 minutes, not client-side, but server-side.

I've found a resource called Later.js but I am not sure how to set it up on a server to automatically initialize and run.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Server-side JS? What!? I don't think that even exists. You can call php pages with crontab though.

Comment: Here's the SpiderMonkey site/docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey

Comment: In that case you need to edit your question, a lot. You should ask 'how to execute spidermonkey every x [unit of time]'

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know without your exact code.

You should be able to do something with jQuery, like:

```
function foo () {
   //your code here
}
foo(); //run function once on startup
setInterval(foo, 5 * 60 * 1000) //and again every five minutes
```

[Later.js](http://bunkat.github.io/later/) *is* a cool library for calculating time in milliseconds, but that's all it does. If you have installed and required it via NPM, you could use it like:

```
var 5min = later.parse.text('every 5 min');
setInterval(foo, 5min);
```

As you can see, you might as well just use standard JS/jQuery to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch, but I am looking to run this on a server, not client side. I'm looking at SpiderMonkey and Rhino, but I am out of my league in understanding some of the docs. The objective is to run the program on a server and never initialize it client-side, only access the mongoDB that the data is stored into.